# RobolectricTestRunner's HelperTestRunner having trouble invoking Jmockit?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, robolectric, jmockit

I'm having problems running tests in IntelliJ using Robolectric and it looks like jMockit might be a factor. My test itself has absolutely no jmockit and in fact the test is now just comparing two strings. I'm working with a large codebase that relies pretty heavily on jmockit, so I think there's an issue with the classpath having jmockit. (I saw something similar but not the same at [can jmockit and robolectric coexist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14780965/can-jmockit-and-robolectric-coexist))

Is there a way to work around this? Am I going to have to blow away all my jmockit tests?

The test code is:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class DefaultAssetFormatterTest {

    @Test
    public void test_asset_formatter() {
        assertThat("12345", equalTo("Fsdafadsf"));
    }

}
```

This is what I see when I run the test in IntelliJ:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failure to invoke method: public static void mockit.integration.junit4.internal.MockFrameworkMethod.validatePublicVoidNoArg(mockit.Invocation,boolean,java.util.List)
    at mockit.internal.util.MethodReflection.invoke(MethodReflection.java:61)
    at mockit.internal.annotations.MockMethodBridge.callMock(MockMethodBridge.java:76)
    at mockit.internal.annotations.MockMethodBridge.invoke(MockMethodBridge.java:41)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.validatePublicVoidNoArg(FrameworkMethod.java)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.validatePublicVoidNoArgMethods(ParentRunner.java:131)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.validateInstanceMethods(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:162)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.collectInitializationErrors(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:102)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.validate(ParentRunner.java:344)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:74)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:55)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$HelperTestRunner.<init>(RobolectricTestRunner.java:643)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.getHelperTestRunner(RobolectricTestRunner.java:261)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:194)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:175)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:77)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:195)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$HelperTestRunner.<init>(RobolectricTestRunner.java:643)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.getHelperTestRunner(RobolectricTestRunner.java:261)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:194)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:175)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    ... 2 more

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No compatible method found: fireTestRunFinished(mockit.Invocation, org.junit.runner.Result)
    at mockit.internal.util.MethodReflection.findCompatibleMethod(MethodReflection.java:138)
    at mockit.internal.annotations.MockState.getMockMethod(MockState.java:112)
    at mockit.internal.annotations.AnnotatedMockStates.getMockMethod(AnnotatedMockStates.java:109)
    at mockit.internal.annotations.MockMethodBridge.callMock(MockMethodBridge.java:65)
    at mockit.internal.annotations.MockMethodBridge.invoke(MockMethodBridge.java:41)
    at org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier.fireTestRunFinished(RunNotifier.java)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:158)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:77)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:195)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to have to upgrade to JMockit **1.5** to avoid this problem.

It occurs because of JMockit's inability to work in the presence of Robolectric's `AsmInstrumentingClassLoader`. Version 1.5 of JMockit makes it more robust in environments with custom classloading.

Comment: Do you mean 1.4? I don't see a 1.5.

Comment: Is the official release of 1.5 tomorrow like the change site says? I'm having issues building it myself; getting WithCaptureTest (among others) throwing _type parameters of <T>T cannot be determined; no unique maximal instance exists for type variable T with upper bounds int,java.lang.Object_ with mvn install and I'm getting _ExpectationsUsingReturnTypeConversionTest.java:108: unclosed character literal_ using ant.