# java.lang.NoSuchMethodException with JMockit 1.5 and Robolectric 2.2

Tags: android, junit, robolectric, jmockit

I'm trying to use JMockit 1.5 with robolectric 2.2 but I get a java.lang.NoSuchMethodException as soon I try to create an Activity. I've reduced the test to this:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
//@RunWith(MyTestRunner.class)
public class Test_login {
  @Test
  public void test_login(@Mocked final Intent in) {
    FragmentActivity frag = Robolectric.buildActivity(MainActivity.class).create().get();
  }
}
```

But I get this stack trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.udg.pds.simpleapp_android.roboelectric.Test_login.test_login()
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:201)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:175)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:77)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:195)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.udg.pds.simpleapp_android.roboelectric.Test_login.test_login()
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1665)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:199)
    ... 19 more
```

I've also tried to use this runner:

```
public class MyTestRunner extends RobolectricTestRunner {
  static { Startup.initializeIfPossible(); }

  public MyTestRunner(Class<?> testClass) throws InitializationError {
    super(testClass);
  }
}
```

But it does not make a difference. I have tried different orders with the classpath (jmockit, robolectric, junit) with no luck. As soon as I try to use @Injectable or @Mocked in a test I get this exception. I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19440349/robolectrictestrunners-helpertestrunner-having-trouble-invoking-jmockit) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14780965/can-jmockit-and-robolectric-coexist) but it didn't help.

Any hint on where is the problem ? Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `NoSuchMethodException` occurs because the Robolectric custom JUnit test runner tries to look up a parameter-less test method, `test_login()`, instead of the actual test method which does have a parameter.

A workaround is to use mock fields (declared with `@Mocked`, `@Injectable`, etc. at the test class level) only, avoiding mock parameters.

Comment: Thanks, that will work!. Anyway, I wonder if this is a robolectric problem that always it ignores the parameters in test methods, or it is an issue of the combination of both frameworks.

Comment: After trying this the exception goes away, but when I try to set some Expectations I got this error "Invalid place to verify expectations". Any hint ?