# JMockit javaagent isn't initializing JMockit

Tags: java, junit, jmockit

I've set up JMockit for use with some JUnit tests also using Robolectric, but I am getting errors.  I'm primarily using maven to run the tests.

When I run the test with **mvn test** and the javaagent configured as specified [here](http://jmockit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/www/tutorial/RunningTests.html) I get the usual exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: JMockit wasn't properly initialized; check that jmockit.jar precedes junit.jar in the classpath (if using JUnit; if not, check the documentation)

I have validated that JMockit is on the classpath *before* JUnit using [`mvn dependency:build-classpath`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/build-classpath-mojo.html) and `mvn test --debug`.  I have also validated that the `-javaagent` argument is appropriately being called using `mvn test --debug`.

Library versions:

- JDK 1.6
- JMockit 1.5
- JUnit 4.8.2
- Robolectric 2.2 *The Robolectric runner prevents me from using the JMockit runner.*
- Maven 3.0.3
- Surefire 2.14.1

The test class follows:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class HelpFragTest {

    FragmentActivity activity;
    FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    @Mocked ActionBarManager actionBarManager;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(FragmentActivity.class).create().resume().get();
        fragmentManager = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
        MyApplication.instance().setActionBarManager(actionBarManager);
    }

    @Test
    public void testShow(){
        new NonStrictExpectations() {{
            Helper.staticMethod(anyString, anyString);
            actionBarManager.clear();
            actionBarManager.setTitle(anyString);
            actionBarManager.refresh();
        }};
        HelpFrag frag = HelpFrag.newInstance();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(frag, StringUtils.EMPTY);
        transaction.commit();

        assertTrue(frag.isVisible());

    }
}
```

---

I've also tried without either the explicit runner or the JavaAgent, in which case I get the following exception from the same code:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid place to record expectations

Comment: Related Question: [java.lang.NoSuchMethodException with JMockit 1.5 and Robolectric 2.2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20080978/16487).

Answer (score 2):

I have run into the same issue, and the problem seems to be that the Robolectric test runner interferes with the JMockit-JUnit integration. See [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jmockit-users/OL3Zx3qw91U).

Comment: It seems you and I run into a lot of the same problems.  If you have a chance please join me in [Android Unit Testing](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44241/android-unit-testing).  If I'm not there just use `@C.Ross` to ping me.

Answer (score 1):

SYMPTOM:
Error when run maven with Jmockit and junit into java project.

MESSAGE:
JMockit wasn't properly initialized; check that jmockit.jar precedes junit.jar in the classpath (if using JUnit; if not, check the documentation)

CAUSES:

Wrong configured in POM.xml file. Jmockit dependencyis is after of junit.

SOLUTIONS:

Edit POM.xml file. The jmockit.jar should be precedes junit.jar then jmockit dependency should be before of junit.

(always put jmockit before of junit)