# Invalid place to record Expectations

Tags: jmockit, expectations

I'm using JMockit 1.14 with Junit 4.

```
private void method()
{
    new NonStrictExpectations()
    {
        {
            firstObject.getLock();
            returns(new Lock());

            secondObject.getDetails();
            result = secondObjectDetails;

            secondObject.isAvailable();
            result = true;
        }
    };
}
```

Is there anything obviously wrong with my code?

Comment: The "Invalid place to record Expectations" error could be caused by [the jMockit agent not being initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20672198/jmockit-javaagent-isnt-initializing-jmockit) correctly.

If that's not the case, then adding the code of the test method with the mock declarations (@Mocked, @Injectable) would help.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved a similar issue (using android studio, junit 4.12 and JMockit 1.20)  by adding

@RunWith(JMockit.class)

outside the test case class, with a couple of import changes.

See JMockit documentation: http://jmockit.org/tutorial/Introduction.html#runningTests

Comment: Please provide a small example to your answer in order to both clarify what you did and to improve your answer's quality.