# Is it possible for test using JMockit to be run with RobolecticTestRunner?

Tags: robolectric, jmockit

Under normal circumstances, using JMockit only requires that the JMockit JARs be declared before the JUnit JAR when running unit tests.

I am encountering the following StackOverflowError when using JMockit mocks in tests run with the RobolecticTestRunner.

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal.getMap(ThreadLocal.java:213)
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:144)
    at mockit.internal.mockups.MockState.update(MockState.java:54)
    at mockit.internal.mockups.MockStates.updateMockState(MockStates.java:93)
    at mockit.internal.state.TestRun.updateMockState(TestRun.java:160)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.validatePublicVoidNoArg(FrameworkMethod.java)
    at mockit.integration.junit4.internal.MockFrameworkMethod.validatePublicVoidNoArg(MockFrameworkMethod.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor12.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at mockit.internal.util.MethodReflection.invokeWithCheckedThrows(MethodReflection.java:106)
    at mockit.internal.mockups.MockMethodBridge.callMock(MockMethodBridge.java:85)
    at mockit.internal.mockups.MockMethodBridge.invoke(MockMethodBridge.java:44)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.validatePublicVoidNoArg(FrameworkMethod.java)
    at mockit.integration.junit4.internal.MockFrameworkMethod.validatePublicVoidNoArg(MockFrameworkMethod.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor12.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at mockit.internal.util.MethodReflection.invokeWithCheckedThrows(MethodReflection.java:106)
    at mockit.internal.mockups.MockMethodBridge.callMock(MockMethodBridge.java:85)
    at mockit.internal.mockups.MockMethodBridge.invoke(MockMethodBridge.java:44)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.validatePublicVoidNoArg(FrameworkMethod.java)
```

Is there any special configuration that would allow for JMockit to function correctly when running unit tests with RobolectricTestRunner? The following discussion makes it look like JMockit with 1.5 release

[RobolectricTestRunner's HelperTestRunner having trouble invoking Jmockit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19440349/robolectrictestrunners-helpertestrunner-having-trouble-invoking-jmockit/19450577#19450577)

and this posting provided a suggestion for creating a custom RobolectricTestRunner that invokes Startup. initializeIfNeeded()

[can jmockit and robolectric coexist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14780965/can-jmockit-and-robolectric-coexist)

However, neither discussion has helped me identify a solution. Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I managed to run a `@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)` test class with JMockit 1.7 also on the classpath, with no errors. I just needed to put `android.jar` after `junit.jar`, since Android includes some JUnit 3.8 classes (like `junit.framework.TestCase`). Can you provide more details so I could try and reproduce the problem?

Comment: I am executing my tests from Maven with dependencies declared in the following order:

Comment: I am executing my tests from Maven with dependencies declared in the following order (dependency version in parentheses):

1. JMockit (1.7)
2. JUnit (4.8.2)
3. Robolectric (2.2)
4. Android SDK (2.3.3_r2)

The JUnit tests are implemented using JUnit 4 annotations

Comment: Ok, I managed to reproduce the exception, so I will be trying to figure out a solution or workaround. It only happens in test classes with the `RobolectricTestRunner`; test classes only using JMockit appear to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working using Robolectric 2.3 and JMockit 1.8 (DO NOT USE HIGHER VERSION OF JMOCKIT for now)

maybe try that?

Comment: Thanks for confirming. This issue was resolved by Rogerio after reporting this issue (released in 1.8)